# How to submit a curl request via Python to return a csv file

Tags: python, curl, pycurl

I have a cURL script that, when run via the CMD Prompt window, returns the requested data.  However I am trying to figure out how to automate this process via Python (either 2.7 - 3.6) so that it returns a csv file instead.  (I am using the latest version of Python allowed when working with either ArcGIS ArcMap and/or ArcGIS Pro mapping software.)

I have basic Python skills and need help getting the script right.  Below is the cURL script I push via the CMD Prompt window.  How do I do this with Python so that it returns a csv file?

I have looked up various examples which seem somewhat different in the parameters required.  I have tried to modify a few, but couldn't get them to work.  I am not set on one method verses another, so I am open to different solutions, just need to find one that works.  My cURL doesn't require a username, just an API key and some basic search parameters.  Most examples I found required both a user name and password.

Current cURL code...

> curl -H "Authorization: Basic myAPIkey"
>   “https://website.com/api/incident?search_from=2019-08-01&search_to=2019-08-31”

I want to be able to download a csv file.
The errors I have been getting vary depending upon which example and method I was trying to replicate.

Thanks for any assistance in advance.

UPDATE

I managed to figure out the Python request option to submit my initial request:

```
import requests,json
headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic APIKEY'}
response = requests.get("https://website.com/api/incident?search_from=2019-08-01&search_to=2019-08-31&country_id=5", headers=headers)
print json.dumps(response.json(), indent=4)
```

It now returns I believe a json file, however I am having issues still on parsing it properly to either save as a csv or as a new Feature Class in ArcGIS.

The print statement returns the following:

> {
>       "message": "", 
>       "total": 1, 
>       "data": {
>           "total": 353, 
>           "results": [
>               {
>                   "mgrs": "33S UR 71235 88779", 
>                   "weight": 0, 
>                   "type_id": "1", 
>                   "longitude": "13.63040400", 
>                   "date": "2019-08-31", 
>                   "latitude": "32.42868600", 
>                   "icon": "assets/images/map_icons/Announcement.png", 
>                   "id": "507188", 
>                   "quantity": "1"
>               }, 
>               {
>                   "mgrs": "33S US 40233 29235", 
>                   "weight": 1, 
>                   "type_id": "3", 
>                   "longitude": "13.29387300", 
>                   "date": "2019-08-31", 
>                   "latitude": "32.78945800", 
>                   "icon": "assets/images/map_icons/ArmedClashes.png", 
>                   "id": "507187", 
>                   "quantity": "1"
>               }
>           ]
>       }
>   }

I want to be able to read and right the "results" list into a csv format with a proper header column.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What format is the data currently being retrieved in?

Comment: Please add code to the question, not the comments.